# Create a repeated action in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

**In SpriteKit, how can I print "Hello World" to the console every 2 seconds?**

In SpriteKit, we're not supposed to use NSTimers or other means of timed loops since they do not listen for `scene.paused`.

I should be using `runAction(SKAction.sequence([firstAction, secondAction, ...])` according to other posts.

I tried this:

```
var wait = SKAction.waitForDuration(1)

func sayHi() {
  println("hello world")
}

runAction(SKAction.sequence([wait, sayHi]))
```

Got this error: `Missing argument for parameter 'completion' in call.`

Comment: you're getting an error because sequence should be an array of SKActions.. you're putting in a closure.  If you want to pass in a closure you need to use SKAction.runBlock({})

Answer (score 5, accepted):

this prints hello world to the console every 2 seconds, forever.

```
self.runAction(SKAction.repeatActionForever(
    SKAction.sequence([
        SKAction.waitForDuration(2),
        SKAction.runBlock({
            println("hello world")
        })
    ])
))
```